# Windows user environment variable vs. system environment variable

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, environment-variables

In Windows, is there any shell/PowerShell command to list user environment variable and system environment variable separately?

If I do -

```
SET TEMP
```

Windows displays the user environment variable instead of system variable for `TEMP`.

I am looking for a shell command/switch to display these variables separately.

Comment: Just have a look with Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment variables.  It does not necessarily match the value of the variable since it can be overridden.

Comment: Yes, User Variable takes precedence. I am trying to list out these variables separately in my script.

Comment: No, parent's environment takes precedence, the child process inherits it.  Sometimes it doesn't.  And the process itself can change it.  The registry just gives the default values.  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment and HKCU\Environment.

Comment: Thanks. I tried searching Microsoft's documentation on the env variable precedence - yet to find one.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In PowerShell, there's no cmdlet for it, but you can use the underlying .NET methods in the Environment class:

```
Write-Host "Machine environment variables"
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables("Machine")

Write-Host "User environment variables"
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables("User")

# This should be the same as 'Get-ChildItem env:', although it isn't sorted.
Write-Host "Process environment variables"
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables("Process")
```

Comment: And to get a specific variable, use `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", "Machine")`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %%a in (`reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" ^| findstr TEMP`)  do @echo System variable TEMP = %%a
for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %%a in (`reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" ^| findstr TEMP`)  do @echo Current user variable TEMP = %%a
```

To use from a command line replace `%%` with `%`.

Output:

```
System variable TEMP = %SystemRoot%\TEMP
Current user variable TEMP = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Note that the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` takes precedance (but for some reason `%USERPROFILE%` is expanded to a shortname when evaluating `%TEMP%`):

```
echo %USERPROFILE%
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\DavidPostill

echo %TEMP%
C:\Users\DAVIDP~1\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Comment: Got to learn something new from those scripts. Thanks, that's helpful.