# In powershell, how can I define all env vars for the next command similar to python's Popen abilities?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

In powershell, how can I...

- explicitly define all the env vars for the next command?
- I don't want any system env vars if possible,
- After this command runs I dont want anything we have done to affect further processes in the shell.

As an example, in python we have the equivalent ability in Popen to pass a dictionary of the full environment to the subprocess, and I'm hoping there might be something similar in Powershell.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is calling PowerShell to run code from within PowerShell, and define $Env vars as the first part of the code being ran by the PowerShell call.  I think, but haven't tried this to verify it, that the $Env vars would exist only for that PowerShell call.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link explains what you need: [Windows user environment variable vs. system environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675480/windows-user-environment-variable-vs-system-environment-variable)

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", "Machine")
```